# First time Javascript Object alert

Tags: javascript, object, alert

You can probably see what I want to do, but I dont know how.

```
function SetupCards() {
    var Cards =
    {
        "1Name": "value1",
        "1Suit": 1,
        "1Number": 2, 
        "1Active": 0
    };



alert( Cards.1Name );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Even if we can figure out what you mean the code to do, you should always explain it and what result it's giving you.

Comment: By convention, function names starting with a capital letter are used for constructors. This doesn't seem to be one, so *setupCards* and *cards* are preferred.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
alert(Cards['1Name']);
```

because the first character of the object item begins with a number.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the ']' at the end, try again.

Comment: You're welcome, but don't forget to click the check mark next to my answer to make it best answer. :)

Comment: The *reason* is that for [*property accessors*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-property-accessors), dot notation can only be used with property names that are valid identifiers, which can't start with a number. Therefore square bracket notation must be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names should not start with a number. Fix them.

```
function SetupCards() {
    var Cards =
    {
        "Name": "value1",
        "Suit": 1,
        "Number": 2, 
        "Active": 0
    };



alert( Cards.Name );
}
```

SetupCards();

Comment: Those are not _variables_. Those are object's properties and as long as you using quotes you can define whatever property name as you want.

Comment: Your code works, but I would like the names with the 1 in front of it. "1Name" instead of "Name".

Comment: So probably you should  have suggested using bracket notation instead of changing the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a variable you can just return an object literal like this, but this is not my prefered way of making a constructor function:

```
function SetupCards () {
    return {
        "1Name": "value1",
        "1Suit": 1,
        "1Number": 2,
        "1Active": 0
    }
}

alert(SetupCards()['1Name']);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j06v3n48/2/)